# Using TouchImageView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to use Justin Toth's C# port of [TouchImageView](https://gist.github.com/justintoth/10663869). The image displays properly (it even reacts to Click event), but it does not scroll or zoom. Since there is no documentation to the code, I am not sure how to use it. Is the zooming and scrolling automatic, do I have to set it or even implement it manually? Here are pieces of my code:

Main.axml (the TouchImageView is located in Customized.Layout namespace)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/alinearLayout2">
    <Button
        p1:text="@string/butNextTurn"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/abutton1" />
    <TextView
        p1:text="Text"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/acoordinates"
        p1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        p1:textColor="@color/brick" />
    <Customized.Layout.TouchImageView
        p1:id="@+id/aview"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Customized.Layout.TouchImageView view = FindViewById<Customized.Layout.TouchImageView>(Resource.Id.aview);

        if (view != null)
        {
            view.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.image);
            view.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;
            view.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some time, **fabionuno** answered my question [here](https://gist.github.com/justintoth/10663869)

In the code of TouchImageView.cs

```
SetOnTouchListener(new TouchImageViewListener(this));
```

should be changed to

```
base.SetOnTouchListener(new TouchImageViewListener(this));
```

Anyway, for large images TouchImageView proved to be very slow (at least in my case). For anyone, who would have similar problem, I recommend using WebView (or your own class inheriting WebView) implementing GestureListener (as stated in the [Xamarin tutorial](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/create_a_gesture_listener/))